# error in deployement tomcat 6

Tags: deployment, tomcat6, netbeans-7

I am trying to deploy a web application using Struts 2 and Hibernate 3 under Netbeans 7.1.2.

I am getting the following error on deployment:

```
Starting of Tomcat failed, the C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.2 startup script is missing.
F:\Projects\CMS2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:794: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed, the C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.2 startup script is missing.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I have checked it out from SVN(collabnet).
What could be the problem with this.
I have referred the some links in so, and google but no luck so far.
I have changed the `tomcat-users` but still no change.

Comment: 2 things to check: 1. remove tomcat server from your netbeans and add it again. 2. check if there is a `startup.bat` in your `${catalina_home/bin}`

Comment: Thanks, I have removed it and added again, but no change. there was'nt any startup.bat in '${catalina_home/bin}'. Now I have added it but no luck.
the line pointed in the error is like

    <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>